# how do i add a loading screen to a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made a loading screen for my website but kinda have no idea on how to attach it to it .

i have to follow in code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

.loading {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loading h1 {
  color: #4df3ff;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: rounds 2s infinite;
}

.loading .color1 {
  border-color: #45f3ff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}

.loading .color2 {
  border-color: #00474d;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s
}

.loading .color3 {
  border-color: #33f1ff;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  animation-delay: 0.4s
}

.loading .color4 {
  border-color: #005f66;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  animation-delay: 0.6s
}

@keyframes rounds {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <h1>Loading..!</h1>
  <div class="circle color1"></div>
  <div class="circle color2"></div>
  <div class="circle color3"></div>
  <div class="circle color4"></div>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
  normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum'
  will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put your loader in a wrapper and make it fit the entire window, then hide it after a certain amount of time.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#loading_wrapper').style.display = 'none';
}, 3000);
```

```css
#loading_wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.loading {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loading h1 {
  color: #4df3ff;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: rounds 2s infinite;
}

.loading .color1 {
  border-color: #45f3ff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}

.loading .color2 {
  border-color: #00474d;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s
}

.loading .color3 {
  border-color: #33f1ff;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  animation-delay: 0.4s
}

.loading .color4 {
  border-color: #005f66;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  animation-delay: 0.6s
}

@keyframes rounds {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading_wrapper">
  <div class="loading">
    <h1>Loading..!</h1>
    <div class="circle color1"></div>
    <div class="circle color2"></div>
    <div class="circle color3"></div>
    <div class="circle color4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
  normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum'
  will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
```